# Forced to use unknown in typescript generic

Tags: typescript, generics

Typescript react, I've got a form builder.  I switch through components, each of which has different types for `value` and what they return in `onChange`.  I wanted to use generics so I knew what type each component expected and returned.

Simplified interface for the form question component (lowest level)

```
interface FormFieldProps<T> {
  value: T;

  onChange: (value: { [key: string]: T }) => void;
}
```

Simplified interface for the FormBuilder component (top level)

```
interface FormBuilderProps<T> {
    fields: FormFieldProps<T>[];
    onChange: (value: { [key: string]: T }) => void;
    formData: { [key: string]: T };
  }
```

The problem I'm running into is that I'm forced to provide a generic at the top level in the FormBuilder and only `unknown` or `any` will fit the bill.  Some components accept `string` or `string[]` or `number` etc.

Component definition
`const FormBuilder = (props: FormBuilderProps<unknown>) => {...}`

I have gotten rid of all my type errors by passing down `unknown` as the generic from the FormBuilder component down to the individual components, but now my typing is all `unknown` and I could possibly pass a `number` to a component that expects a `string`, etc.

**Edited**

The issue arises when I try to create some typed data for FormBuilderProps.  My generic  has to be passed from top down.  If I provide `string`, it works for the TEXT component, but `boolean is not assignable to type string` for the SWITCH component.  Will I have to pass every conceivable option for T and type guard in each component?

Each item in `fields` is passed through a js switch() based on componentType and the appropriate component is rendered.  If those enums could be used to narrow the type of T, that'd be helpful.

```
export const formBuilderData: FormBuilderProps<string> = {
  fields: [
    {
      index: 1,
      columnName: 'columnName',
      componentType: PureComponentType.TEXT,
      value: 'alphabet',
    },
    {
      index: 2,
      columnName: 'bestBear',
      componentType: PureComponentType.SWITCH,
      value: true,
  ],
  readOnly: false,
  formData: {},
};
```

Comment: Can't you make `FormBuilder` a generic function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4n1XN)? If so, I guess I could write up an answer; if not, could you [edit] the question to demonstrate with code why that doesn't work for you?  Let me know either way (mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.) Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz There's too much code to share, but the idea is JSON which makes up a form.  Each field is the props to some component.  Props are the same except for the value accepted and returned via value and onChange.  In the end, we'll just write quick JSON snippets to make a new form rather than React.

Comment: "There's too much code to share" You should make a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates what you need.  It doesn't have to be your full code base, just a toy example that has enough moving pieces to demonstrate your problem.  Your added snippet isn't valid TS (I see at least one typo) and refers to external/private types not declared (what's `PureComponentType`?) and doesn't agree with the rest of your code (`index`, `columnName`, `componentType`, etc). If you could put together something, I'm sure I could provide a suggestion. But right now it would take too much guesswork on my part.

Comment: I mean, for all I know, [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdrgXW) is closer to what you want, where you specify the whole object type and not each field separately.  Or maybe you do have an enum as you were saying and we can generate the types as a union of possible types... but for that I'd need to see a [mre].  Anyway, if you do provide one and want me to take another look, mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.

Comment: @jcalz I appreciate your time and help.  Getting a reproducible demo was going to take a lot more time than I had since we're using a lot of in-home packages for the UI components.  I tried something different that worked out, maybe not as elegantly though.  I'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution isn't as elegant as I'd like but it works.

1.) Removed the generic from the top level interface

```
export interface FormBuilderProps {
  fields: FieldComponentTypes[];
  onChange: (value: { [key: string]: Pick<FieldComponentTypes, 'value'> }) => void;
  formData: { [key: string]: Pick<FieldComponentTypes, 'value'> };
}
```

2.) Kept generic for the individual field items

```
export interface FormFieldProps<T> {
  index: number;
  columnName: string;
  value?: T;
  onChange?: (value: { [key: string]: Pick<FieldComponentTypes, 'value'> }) => void;
}
```

3.) The less elegant part: I made an interface for each component and passed the appropriate generic type.  Now my switch component knows exactly what type the component gets.

```
export interface TextFieldComponent extends FormFieldProps<string> {
  componentType: PureComponentType.TEXT;
}
```

4.) Lastly, combined all my component interfaces

```
export type FieldComponentTypes =
  | AutoCompleteFieldComponent
  | DateFieldComponent
  | DropdownFieldComponent
  | MultiSelectFieldComponent
  | TextFieldComponent
  | SwitchFieldComponent;
```